# Loading the Model relationship from RAM in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

When we load a Laravel Eloquent model with it's relations, like this:

```
$user = User::with('Interest')->find(1);
```

It queries MySQL as follows:

```
100 Prepare   select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = ? limit 1
100 Execute   select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = '1' limit 1
100 Close stmt        
100 Prepare   select `interest_id`, `user_interests`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `user_interests`.`interest_id` as `pivot_interest_id` from `interests` inner join `user_interests` on `interests`.`id` = `user_interests`.`interest_id` where `user_interests`.`user_id` in (?)
100 Execute   select `interest_id`, `user_interests`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `user_interests`.`interest_id` as `pivot_interest_id` from `interests` inner join `user_interests` on `interests`.`id` = `user_interests`.`interest_id` where `user_interests`.`user_id` in ('1')
100 Close stmt 
100 Quit
```

On the next line I want to access the loaded `Interest` model, which in my opinion was already eager-loaded by the `::with` statement. However when I try to access the `interest_id` like so:

```
$user->interest->interest_id;
```

I see another database lookup appear in MySQL query logging accessing the same already pre-loaded relation:

```
100 Prepare   select `interest_id`, `user_interests`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `user_interests`.`interest_id` as `pivot_interest_id` from `interests` inner join `user_interests` on `interests`.`id` = `user_interests`.`interest_id` where `user_interests`.`user_id` = ?
100 Execute   select `interest_id`, `user_interests`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `user_interests`.`interest_id` as `pivot_interest_id` from `interests` inner join `user_interests` on `interests`.`id` = `user_interests`.`interest_id` where `user_interests`.`user_id` = '1'
100 Close stmt        
100 Quit
```

I expected Laravel to provide me with the already loaded relation, but instead it queried MySQL again. I saw that when I use `getRelation('Interest')`, that it does return the relation already loaded on the `User::with('Interest')` and not query MySQL again, like so:

```
$user->getRelation("Interest")->interest_id;
```

I was wondering if this is the way to go and if my expectations of eager-loading with `::with` are completely wrong? Or maybe there are other best practices to access the preloaded relations instead of querying MySQL again. It seems to me that querying the database several times for the same information is more expensive.

**User Model**

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
use App\Models;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

    public function Interest()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Interest', 'user_interests', 'user_id', 'interest_id')->select(array('interest_id'));
    }

}
```

**Interest Model**

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Interest extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'interests';

    protected $fillable = ['description', 'parent_id'];

    protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

}
```

Comment: that behavior is not normal. Please provide your model code where you define your relationships. Why do you use "Interest" when you  eager load, but "interest" when you access it?

Comment: @JaviStolz, your comment brought the 'Capital' issue to my attention. I've changed the function declaration in the User model to lowercase plural like so: `public function interests() { ... } ` and offcourse where it got called and everything works as expected now. Strange though that it also worked with the capital issue and not throw an exception.

Comment: Try adding the reverse relationship. Also try removing the `->select(array('interest_id'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is `$user->interest->interest_id;` and your function is `public function Interest()`

PHP functions are case sensitive.